# Applying function to a slot of all S4 objects in a list

Tags: r, text-mining, nested-lists, r-s4

I'm new to R and to scripting, but I bet you can help me!

I have a list of 39 imported xml that are organized in S4 objects. This data is for text-mining of biomedical literature.

I need to combine all PMID slots (from all 39 S4 objects) into one, check for duplicate numbers and then apply a function to all of them.

So, I've tried a bunch of different things with no success yet to apply recursively.

The list is **data_xml**;
The slots I need are all **PMID**;

The effect is to attain a object that can even be numeric of all the PMIDs of all the 39 S4 objects.

I've included a picture to better show the structure. 
[R clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8aCz.png)

Comment: `lapply(data_xml, slot, name = "PMID")` should get you a `list` of all the PMID slots from your S4 list. You can then do other processing. If you can construct a small example and describe more about your goal we can probably help more.

Comment: Thank you so much, after this input I could perform all the other actions!